# Is there a way to insert images to a TreeView node label?

Tags: c#, image, treeview, icons

I would like to insert an image to a TreeView node label. I can't use the node's icon because it's already used for other purposes. The other solution would be the ability to have 2 icons per node.

Comment: what is your program win or wpf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to expand `TreeNode` by some `Image SecondIcon` property, add collection of them to your `TreeView` and then subscribe to `TreeView.DrawNode` event.

Here you can find some more hints and example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode.aspx.